# Grails install-plugin destination folder

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is there a way to customize the directory where "grails install-plugin" installs a plugin?

The point is, I upgraded from 1.0.3 to 1.3.3 and the destination dir has changed from the current to the grails working dir, but our app relies on the plugin being in the current dir.

I'd assume I can change the script in the grails dir, but that would be unportable solution - we'd have to change these scripts on every machine where grails is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit BuildConfig.groovy (copy one from a new empty project if you didn't already) and add the property

```
grails.project.plugins.dir = 'plugins'
```

and it'll work like it did in 1.0.x

Comment: please could you mention for grails 3 (build.gradle) ?

Comment: plugins in Grails 1 and 2 are zip files with source that are unpacked and used as part of your application, but in Grails 3+ they're compiled into jar files, so there's no concept of a plugin destination folder. They're jar dependencies like 'regular' jars you would see in a Maven repo.

Comment: So, is there any way I can import all jars in my project plugins directory using build.gradle or ./gradlew ?